# Eclipse: Cannot install CDT because of a conflicting dependency

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

my eclipse has been configured for Java and pydev, now i want to configure C/C++ development tools with Eclipse. i dont want to download the whole Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers, for it is not convenient. so i decided to install CDT in my Eclipse.

`Help` ==> `Install New Software`, then input `http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/indigo`, waited for a while, and chose the following `CDT Main Features`, `CDT Optional Features`, and Next, then an error occurred.

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: C/C++ DSF GDB Debugger Integration 4.0.0.201106081058 (org.eclipse.cdt.gnu.dsf.feature.group 4.0.0.201106081058)
  Software being installed: C/C++ Development Tools SDK 8.0.2.201202111925 (org.eclipse.cdt.sdk.feature.group 8.0.2.201202111925)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    GDB DSF Debugger Integration Core 4.0.0.201106081058 (org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.gdb 4.0.0.201106081058)
    GDB DSF Debugger Integration Core 4.0.2.201202111925 (org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.gdb 4.0.2.201202111925)
    GDB DSF Debugger Integration Core 4.0.1.201109151620 (org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.gdb 4.0.1.201109151620)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: C/C++ Development Tools 8.0.2.201202111925 (org.eclipse.cdt.feature.group 8.0.2.201202111925)
    To: org.eclipse.cdt.gnu.dsf.feature.group [4.0.1.201202111925]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: C/C++ DSF GDB Debugger Integration 4.0.0.201106081058 (org.eclipse.cdt.gnu.dsf.feature.group 4.0.0.201106081058)
    To: org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.gdb [4.0.0.201106081058]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: C/C++ DSF GDB Debugger Integration 4.0.1.201202111925 (org.eclipse.cdt.gnu.dsf.feature.group 4.0.1.201202111925)
    To: org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.gdb [4.0.2.201202111925]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: C/C++ Development Tools SDK 8.0.2.201202111925 (org.eclipse.cdt.sdk.feature.group 8.0.2.201202111925)
    To: org.eclipse.cdt.feature.group [8.0.2.201202111925]
```

i have googled for a lot of time, but still cannot find a valid solution. can anyone give a hand to me? thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you get to select the GDB DSF version while trying to install ? Seems like there is an incompatible version of it is already installed

Comment: How to select the GDB DSF version? @prajeeshkumar

Comment: During your installation there will be one dialog to select the features you want, it is in a tree format, check whether the GDB DSF is there

Comment: Yes, it does have GDB DSF: `C/C++ DSF GDB Debug Integration`, do you have some good idea? @prajeeshkumar

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Now i use ubuntu, and using the command `sudo apt-get install eclipse-cdt` directly solves the problem. It's a little strange that why there is a conflict when installs CDT using eclipse's`Install New Software`.

Comment: This is not really a solution to the question you asked. Just a workaround!

Answer (score 0):

I faced with this problem, too. I just download the c/c++ mode of eclipse which already includes CDT. It works. If you couldn't fix it, you can try this way. It is better than nothing.

Comment: Thanks. i also have two eclipses now: eclipse and c/c++. it works but a little inconvenient.

Answer (score 0):

Normally if I see this many errors, it's because I have picked the wrong update site... maybe a silly question, but do you actually have the Eclipse Indigo base version installed? You can check with `Help`->`About Eclipse`, second line down.

Answer (score 0):

That answer referring to Help->About was a HUGE help. Once there I clicked on the Installation Details button, checked everything CDT/C++ related and clicked Uninstall. Once Eclipse restarted, I was able to install CDT without any problems whatsoever.

TH

Answer (score 0):

this looks very similar to a problem I had. In my case it was that some of the packages in the Optional Extras are already implicitly included in the CDT (such as the GDB DSF packages) and so there are conflicts when you try to install both packages.

If you highlight each package you want in the optional extras it will say in the short comment line describing the package weather or not a version of that package is included by default in the CDT, if it is deselect. Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a little late, but try installing the base CDT package by itself first. Restart Eclipse and then install the CDT Optional Features, this time ticking the "Hide items that are already installed" checkbox. This solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar dilemma as you did. In my case, I downloaded CDT Main Features first and had all the boxes checked in the window. Especially the box that said, "Contact all update sites during install to find required software." Afterwards, I installed "CDT Optional Features" with all the boxes checked as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Kepler Service Release 1 on Windows 8.1, 64-bit.

I encountered this exact behaviour when I tried installing CDT by using these options:
[image]

Do not select both `C/C++ Development Tools` and `C/C++ Development Tools SDK`. This will result in the CDT help files being available, but the C/C++ perspective and C/C++ project type being unavailable, due to probably a package collision (although strangely, nothing was showing up in my workspace `.log` file).

The correct configuration is to select just the `C/C++ Development Tools`, unless of course you want to contribute to CDT, in which case you'd select the `C/C++ Development Tools SDK`. Most users will be content with just the development tools. The following selection worked for me.

[image]